Problem with calculating the variance of different sounds
Problem:

In a layered crystal with weak connections between layers, the dispersion law of acoustic backgrounds has the form
$$\omega _1=s_1q_{||}, \ \ \omega _2=s_1q_{||}, \ \ \omega _3=Sq^2_{||},$$
where $q_{||}=\sqrt{q_x^2+q_y^2}$ is the absolute value of the wave vector in the crystal layer plane, $s_{1,2}$ is the speed of sound ("longitudinal" and "transverse" waves , polarized in the plane of the layer), $S$ is a parameter that describes the dispersion of the bending will of the layers. Determine the temperature dependence of the heat capacity of the crystal at low temperatures $\left ( T\ll T_{D} \right )$, where $T_{D}$ is the Debye temperature

Attempted solutions:
I looked a lot of places and couldn’t find how to look for the average sound. We have three all-subsonic modes; in order to integrate the densities of states of normal, we need to understand how they add up, but they don’t add up directly (I could be wrong)
We can say that different modes have different dispersion laws and, accordingly, different speeds of sound. This is definitely true! But they need to be counted together and usually (I could be wrong) this cannot be solved by pure summation of modes
Can anyone show me how to calculate (sum) correctly?

Why do you think that the density of states isn't additive?   If there are $n_1(\epsilon) , d\epsilon$ modes of type 1 with energies between $\epsilon$ and $\epsilon + d \epsilon$, and there are $n_2(\epsilon) , d\epsilon$ modes of type 2, then surely there are $[n_1(\epsilon) + n_2(\epsilon)] , d\epsilon$ modes in total in that range.

Yes, good, but how to calculate it?
